# What does it mean by Expected Benefits need to be measurable in Prince2

Tags: prince2

What does it mean by Expected Benefits need to be measurable in Prince2 ? However, benefits are not always measurable right? So basically in Prince2 , benefits can be unmeasurable?

Comment: Are you asking whether benefits are always measurable or whether under Prince2 benefits are permitted to be unmeasurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PRINCE2 definition of a benefit is "The measurable improvement resulting from an outcome perceived as an advantage by one or more stakeholders." (from the glossary in the official PRINCE2 manual).

Now you need to make a distinction between output, outcome and benefit:

- An outcome is "the result of the change".
- An output is "a specialist product that is handed over to a user(s)."

Let's take an example:

- you are building a new webshop for your website (the output)
- in order to increase the sales revenue by attracting new/online customers (the outcome)
- the 1st year you expect to have $50k of online sales revenue, the 2nd year... (the benefit)

The output is typically expressed as more or less of something (e.g. more online customers, more online revenue). The benefit is how much more or less, so this needs to be a number to be measurable.